Leaflet heatmap 'getImageData' Javascript error in Android Webview (chromium)
Each time I attempt to display a Leaflet heatmap in an Android WebView object I get the following error in logcat from chromium and the map never displays:
"Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source height is 0.", source: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/python-visualization/folium@main/folium/templates/leaflet_heat.min.js
Yet the exact same page loads and displays the heatmap just fine in a GeckoView browser - org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoView.
(The WebView issue happens on both of my test devices - one runs OS#9 and the other OS#14.)
Has anyone experienced and resolved this WebView issue?
Thanks.

Check https://github.com/mourner/simpleheat/pull/34
